# Sending email using cURL with a password with special character in bash script

Tags: bash, curl, smtp

I have an SMTP configuration like the follows: (everything is dummy data)

```
SMTP_USERNAME="fakenews@yahoo.comg"
SMTP_SERVER="smtp.office365.com"
SMTP_PASSWORD='rdjsllskdslsds!'
SMTP_PORT="587"
EMAIL_FROM="support@fakernews.com"
EMAIL_TO="rfakeuser@fakernews.com"
```

Note the "!" mark at the end of the password. This cannot be changed.

When I run the below command with everything hardcoded, it works fine, and an email is sent.

```
curl --url smtp://smtp.office365.com:587 --mail-from support@fakernews.com --mail-rcpt rfakeuser@fakernews.com --upload-file tempemailbody_1.txt --user fakenews@yahoo.comg:rdjsllskdslsds! --ssl
```

However, when I replace them with variables, as below, I keep getting access denied.

```
curl --url "smtp://$SMTP_SERVER:$SMTP_PORT" --mail-from $EMAIL_FROM --mail-rcpt $EMAIL_TO --upload-file tempemailbody_1.txt  --user "$SMTP_USERNAME:$SMTP_PASSWORD" --ssl
```

The error message is :

```
curl: (9) remote access denied: 501
```

I think that this is because somehow the variable interpretation is causing the issue, but I cant figure out what is it. What should I change in the command to make it work ?

Comment: Always quote your variables.

Comment: Should `yahoo.comg` be `yahoo.com`?

Comment: @Barmar, the domain names are not real. Just dummy data for SO.

Comment: There must be a problem with how you're setting the variables, since `curl` doesn't care where the values come from. My guess is the script has CRLF newlines, fix it with `dos2unix`

Comment: It is not the CRLF newlines. If I just type in all the above commands directly into the shell also it throws the error. And actually, i had it working fine even with variables, but with a different set of username and password. That is why my suspicion is with the password having special character

Comment: The password has the same special character when you type it by hand without the variable.

Comment: Use `set -x` to see a trace of the script operation with variables expanded.